# PL/SQL how to get result from a function that returns type table of

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to call a function that returns `TABLE OF MyTable%ROWTYPE`.

I did the following:

```
 DECLARE
   TYPE type_tab1 IS TABLE OF  Table1%ROWTYPE; 
   v_result1 type_tab1;
BEGIN

   v_result1 := myfunction(p_1, p_2, p_3);

END;
```

But it does not work - I am getting an error:

> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: The information you provided is insufficient to provide you a solution. Show us the definition of `Table1`, the contents of `myfunction` and also the definition of it's return type ( the object and it's nested table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle 11g - how to return record from function with table join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762656/oracle-11g-how-to-return-record-from-function-with-table-join)

Comment: `v_result1` needs to be defined as whatever type `myfunction` returns, not some local type defined in your block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide some info which might be useful, so - have a look at this example, see if it helps.

First, prepare everything we need:

```
SQL> create or replace type td as object
  2    (deptno number,
  3     dname  varchar2(20),
  4     loc    varchar2(20));
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type tty is table of td;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function myfunction(p_deptno in number)
  2  return tty is
  3    l_tty tty := tty();
  4  begin
  5    select td(deptno, dname, loc)
  6      bulk collect into l_tty
  7      from dept
  8      where deptno = p_deptno;
  9
 10    return l_tty;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from table(myfunction(10));

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
```

Your piece of code:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    v_result tty;
  3  begin
  4    v_result := myfunction(10);
  5    dbms_output.put_line(v_result(1).dname);
  6  end;
  7  /
ACCOUNTING

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I tried using `select * from table(mypackage.myfunction(id =>10, field1=>'Test', status => 'Active'));` to view the data in TOAD but getting an error saying that `mypackage` is an invalid data type.. How can I run this in TOAD?